# Custom Function class

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project that involves constructing functions from other functions. I had the idea of writing a class to simplify things but I haven't been able to get it to work without resorting to using `__proto__`.

Here's basically what my vision is.

```
function MyFunction () {
    // ...
}
var myFn = new MyFunction();
myFn(); // executes without error
myFn instanceof MyFunction; // returns true
```

The following code does just that using `__proto__`

```
function MyFunction () {
    var fn = function () { return 'hello'; };
    fn.__proto__ = this;
    return fn;
}
var myFn = new MyFunction();
alert( myFn() ); // hello
alert( myFn instanceof MyFunction ); // true
```

Here's something I've tried using `valueOf`

```
function MyFunction () {
    this.fn = function () { return 'hello'; };
    this.valueOf = function () { return this.fn; };
}
var myFn = new MyFunction();
alert( myFn instanceof MyFunction ); // true
alert( myFn.valueOf()() ); // hello
alert( myFn() ); // error
```

And here's something else extending the function to contain all the properties of `MyFunction`.

```
function MyFunction () {
    this.foo = 'hello'
    var fn = function () { return 'hello'; };
    for ( var i in this ) {
        fn[ i ] = this[ i ];
    }
    return fn;
}
var myFn = new MyFunction();
alert( myFn() ); // hello
alert( myFn.foo ); // hello
alert( myFn instanceof MyFunction ); // false
```

I don't want to use `__proto__` because it's non-standard. Also, this was kind of a freak idea, I'd really like to get it to work, but if it's not possible I'll live. But I guess my question is, is what I'd like to do possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fascinating idea. I don't believe you can do it with standard ECMAScript yet, not even using ES5.

ES5 gives us better access to and control over the prototype, including providing a means of setting the prototype when creating objects (without having to go through constructor functions) with `Object.create`, but you can't construct *functions* via that mechanism. And that's what you would have to do, because `instanceof` uses the abstract spec `[[HasInstance]]` method, which is currently only implemented by functions, and the [function implementation of it](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.3) works by seeing if the object's underyling prototype (`[[Proto]]`) is `===` to the function's `prototype` property. The only *standard* way to set the object's underlying prototype is to create it via `new MyFunction` or via `Object.create`, and neither mechanism creates a function object.

ES.next may make this possible. There's a proposal that's been promoted to "harmony" status (so, fairly advanced) for a "[set prototype operator](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproto_operator)", `<|`, which is intended to solve many of the problems currently solved via `__proto__`. One of the things it's for is "Setting the prototype of a function to something other than `Function.prototype`". Using it (in its current form), your `MyFunction` would look something like this:

```
function MyFunction () {
  return MyFunction.prototype <| function () { return 'hello'; };
}
MyFunction.prototype = Object.create(Function.prototype);
```

That last bit is to make it that `MyFunction.prototype` is an object with the prototype `Function.prototype`, so that functions constructed via `MyFunction` have `call`, `apply`, `bind`, etc.

Comment: Bummer, I also heard some form of `__proto__` will be officially added in the next ES too. I guess I'm just ahead of my time :(. Oh well.