# Can I make an invocable function from an object as the other way around?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Let's assume I have a function:

```
var func = function(param){return param + 1;};
```

Given that functions are objects, I can add properties to it:

```
func.prop = 'foo';
```

Both `func(4)` and `func.prop` should work. But now let's say that I have an object:

```
var obj = {prop: 'foo'};
```

...and I want to make it invocable as an increment function.  Is this possible?

Comment: I asked a similar question not too long ago. See here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227623/custom-function-class

Comment: ... "as an increment function" ... **what?**

Comment: Blasted comment timer. Your idea seems simpler than mine. Is there any reason why you can't use a function with some cached properties for this? You can refer to the function using `arguments.callee` if you need to access it. I'm assuming you want `this` to work, even if you got an object to behave like a function `this` would still refer to `window`. Could you give us more information on what you're trying to do? Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/YhxDD/

Comment: @Pointy look at the question above... **`return param + 1`**

Comment: OK I understand now; I just was somewhat confused as that is far from possible in JavaScript; you can't make an object act like a function unless it actually is a function, as explained in the good answer you got.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to make [an Object] invocable as an increment function. Is this possible?

No.

Objects created by the Object constructor do not have in internal [`[[Call]]`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1) method and therefore can't be called. It's the special `[[Call]]` method that makes a function a function. Note that the Object constructor is a Function, but it makes plain Objects, not functions.

While Functions inherit from `Object.prototype`, they are [created by the Function constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2). Built–in constructors have extra powers given to them by ECMA-262. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad idea (IMO, it's a lot of overhead for lame syntactic sugar), but it can be done.

```
function InvokableObject(properties) {
    var propName,
        invoke = properties.invoke,
        fn = typeof invoke === 'string' ? 
            function () {
                return fn[invoke].call(fn, arguments);
            } : 
            function () {
                return invoke.call(fn, arguments);
            };
    delete properties.invoke;
    for (propName in properties) {
        if (properties.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
            fn[propName] = properties[propName];
        }
    }
    return fn;
}
```

Now, you can specify a function as the "invoke" property, and when you call the object, it will run:

```
var incrementable = InvokableObject({
    value: 0,
    invoke: function () {
        this.value += 1;
        return this.value;
    }
});

console.log(incrementable.value); //0
console.log(incrementable()); //1
console.log(incrementable()); //2
```

Alternately, you can specify the name of the invokation function:

```
var incrementable = InvokableObject({
    value: 0,
    invoke: 'increment',
    increment: function () {
        this.value += 1;
        return this.value;
    }
});

console.log(incrementable.value); //0
console.log(incrementable()); //1
console.log(incrementable()); //2
```

Seriously, though, don't do this.  Just call obj.increment or whatever.